# Duplicate declaration in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Consider this code:

```
var a = [];

for (var i in a)
  /* nothing */;

var i : number;

i = 9;
```

If I compile this, the compiler complains about the last line, saying, "Cannot convert 'number' to 'string'".

Presumably the for..in loop created `i` as a string, but I would have expected the compiler to complain about `var i : number` rather than wait until `i = 9` before it complained.

If I change `var i : number` to `var i : number = 8`, the compiler still doesn't complain until it reaches `i = 9`.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had originally declared the variable it would warn you where you predict. For example, if you placed this line at the top of your code:

```
var i: string;
```

It would warn you of the duplicate identifier on the line:

```
var i: number;
```

It doesn't detect the duplicate identifier when you declare `i` in the for statement, perhaps it should - so you end up with a different error, which is when you assign a value of the wrong type.

If you want the duplicate identifier warning, which is the first and foremost error here, your best bet is to log the bug on http://typescript.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you, Steve. I did as you suggested: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/771

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, to understand what's going on you have to understand how JavaScript behaves, especially around the area regarding hoisting.  Essentially, the code you have above is the same as:

```
var a = [],
    i;

for (i in a)
  /* nothing */;

i = 9;
```

Since `i` is first encountered in your for statement, its type is becoming a string. `for (key: string in someVar) { }`.

Here's an article that describes hoisting and scoping in JavaScript:
http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Comment: But that doesn't explain why the compiler doesn't complain about `var i : number = 8`.

Comment: The compiler complains for me when I do `var i: number = 8;`, at least in version 0.8.2.

Comment: I'm using 0.8.3, and it doesn't complain.

Comment: Must be a new bug in 0.8.3. It complains for me in 0.8.2, but not in http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/ Wierdly, in 0.8.3 you can trace `typeof(i)` and it will tell you 'number', but if you then try `i * 10` you get the error described by @oz1cz in the OP.